Sandboxed macOS app can't access Photos library
I have an Electron app built for macOS, and it was distributed via 'Developer ID' for years, it worked well and I was able to access the photos in the system Photos library. Surely I already have the 'NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription' key in Info.plist.
Recently we are trying to publish this app to Mac App Store, so I have to turn on the sandbox, after that the app starts giving XPC errors while accessing the Photos library. The errors look like:
PHAuthorizationStatus: Authorized
CoreData: XPC: sendMessage: failed #0
CoreData: XPC: Unable to sendMessage: to server
...
CoreData: XPC: sendMessage: failed #7
CoreData: XPC: Unable to connect to server with options {
    NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey = 1;
    NSXPCStoreServerEndpointFactory = "<PLXPCPhotoLibraryStoreEndpointFactory: 0x7fc67e8af370>";
    skipModelCheck = 1;
}
CoreData: XPC: Unable to load metadata: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={Problem=Unable to send to server; failed after 8 attempts.}
CoreData: fault: Unable to create token NSXPCConnection.  NSXPCStoreServerEndpointFactory 0x7fc67e8af370 -newEndpoint returned nil
CoreData: error: Failed to create NSXPCConnection

It seems the app could detect the current 'PHAuthorizationStatus' which is 'Authorized', but it can't fetch the photos from the Photos library (using PhotoKit).
I learned from here that I could look for errors from the sandboxd daemon, so I did that, here is what I saw:
Sandbox: Picture Keeper(32625) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.photos.service
Violation:       deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.photos.service
Process:         Picture Keeper [32625]
Path:            /Applications/Picture Keeper.app/Contents/MacOS/Picture Keeper
Load Address:    0x103bd3000
Identifier:      com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeepermas
Version:         4575 (4.5.75)
Code Type:       x86_64 (Native)
Parent Process:  Picture Keeper [1]
Responsible:    /Applications/Picture Keeper.app/Contents/MacOS/Picture Keeper
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2024-08-26 16:16:14.645 EDT
OS Version:      macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Release Type:    User
Report Version:  8

MetaData: {"process_path":["Users","Kevin","Projects","Electron","picturekeeper-electron","dist","picturekeeper","mas-dev","Picture Keeper.app","Contents","MacOS","Picture Keeper"],"apple-internal":false,"primary-filter":"global-name","policy-description":"Sandbox","flags":5,"platform-policy":false,"build":"macOS 14.5 (23F79)","process-path":"\/Applications\/Picture Keeper.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Picture Keeper","responsible-process-path":"\/Applications\/Picture Keeper.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Picture Keeper","primary-filter-value":"com.apple.photos.service","platform_binary":"no","responsible-process-signing-id":"com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeepermas","hardware":"Mac","target":"com.apple.photos.service","action":"deny","mach_namespace":1,"checker-pid":1,"container":"\/Users\/Kevin\/Library\/Containers\/com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeepermas\/Data","binary-in-trust-cache":false,"team-id":"LU744924UY","process":"Picture Keeper","global-name":"com.apple.photos.service","platform-binary":false,"pid":32625,"summary":"deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.photos.service","checker":"launchd","responsible-process-team-id":"xxxxx","operation":"mach-lookup","normalized_target":["com.apple.photos.service"],"errno":1,"uid":501,"profile-flags":0,"profile-in-collection":false,"sandbox_checker":"launchd","signing-id":"com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeepermas","release-type":"User"}

I believe I already have the necessary entitlements for the Photos library, see:
codesign -d --entitlements - /Applications/Picture\ Keeper.app/Contents/MacOS/Picture\ Keeper

[Dict]
    [Key] com.apple.application-identifier
    [Value]
        [String] xxxx.com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeepermas
    [Key] com.apple.developer.team-identifier
    [Value]
        [String] xxxx
    [Key] com.apple.security.app-sandbox
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.application-groups
    [Value]
        [Array]
            [String] xxxx.com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeepermas
    [Key] com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-only
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.assets.music.read-only
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-write
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.device.usb
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.network.client
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.network.server
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.personal-information.location
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.personal-information.photos-library
    [Value]
        [Bool] true

By the way, the Photos library related code was built into a .node file (which is a dylib), and it will be loaded by the main executable during runtime.
Anything I missed? Thank you!

For anyone who are building Mac App Store apps with Electron and met similar XPC errors, it seems the issue has been addressed since Electron v26.

Electron 25.9.8 with Node 18.15.0: Doesn't work
Electron 26.0.0 with Node 18.16.1: Works fine

